# Где лучше хранить данные для быстроты доступа, python

Tags: python, база-данных, json, highload

Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше обновлять множество данных которые обновляются раз в минуту.

Используя базу данных для 100 активных пользователей, у которых 1 поле меняется раз минуту, я представляю как будет работать, и не думаю что сильно будет нагружать БД.

Но смотря в будущее понимаю что такой способ будет долгим если будет 1000 пользователей и больше, у которых надо ежеминутно обновлять 1 поле(а может и больше, пока в планах только 1)

Я думал сделать прослойку между БД и кодом в виде json, но не уверен что это будет верно. 
К сожалению нет опыта в разработке высока нагруженных систем. Если есть тематические статьи, с удовольствием бы прочитал.

Как вы думаете где лучше хранить данные ?

Идея в прослойки json состоит в том что бы сохранять дневные данные туда, по 2 -ум полям, id - пользователя и часто обновляемое поле, а в конце дня обновлять их в бд.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с Redis

Comment: Или с memcached.

Comment: Начните работу без всякой прослойки, возможно, для 1000 пользователей все еще будет работать нормально. Напишите только все функции обращения к БД в отдельном модуле. А уж когда затормозится, займётесь оптимизацией...